# Get Cell Value in C# Gridview when Button clicked on row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridviewMain. Whenever I click the CLOSE linkbutton for row 1 I want to get the value aa. Click Close on row 2 get the value of bb. Any ideas.

```
A    B   C  
aa  xx   3  CLOSE 
bb  yy   4  CLOSE
cc  zz   5  CLOSE
```

aspx

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="afield" HeaderText="A" 
     SortExpression="afield" >
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 </asp:BoundField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="bfield" HeaderText="B" SortExpression="cfield" >
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="cfield" HeaderText="C" SortExpression="cfield" >
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </asp:BoundField>
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="CloseClicked" Text="Close"></asp:LinkButton>

        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Asssuming that you are using `BoundFields` for the first three columns and you want to handle the `LinkButton`-click event (instead of the e.g. `RowCommand` of the `GridView`):

```
protected void CloseLinkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var closeLink = (Control) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) closeLink.NamingContainer;
    string firstCellText = row.Cells[0].Text; // here we are
}
```

If you are using `TemplateFields` and the value `aa` is in a Label (e.g. `LblValue`):

```
Label lblValue = (Label) row.FindControl("LblValue"); // lblValue.Text = "aa"
```

Comment: @Apollo: You don't need to handle the `RowCommand`, just handle the `LinkButton`'s `Click`-event: `<asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  OnClick="CloseLinkClicked" Text="Close"></asp:LinkButton>`

Answer (score 3):

Use data keys for this. Much simpler:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SomeValue, AnotherValue" ... >
```

And then in code-behind, just get the keys associated with the row:

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var someValue = GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["SomeValue"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a `CommandName` to your `LinkButton` column in the `GridView` markup. From there you will also need to wire up the `OnRowCommand` event to handle your `Close` command.

Here is an example of using an `Add` command on a `GridView`:

```
Markup:
<asp:gridview id="ContactsGridView" datasourceid="ContactsSource" allowpaging="true" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false" onrowcommand="ContactsGridView_RowCommand" runat="server">
    <columns>
       <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" commandname="Add" text="Add"/>
       <asp:boundfield datafield="ContactID" headertext="Contact ID"/>
       <asp:boundfield datafield="FirstName" headertext="First Name"/> 
       <asp:boundfield datafield="LastName" headertext="Last Name"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>

Code-Behind:
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
        // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
        // property to an Integer.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
        // by the user from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

        // Create a new ListItem object for the contact in the row.     
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text) + " " +
        Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);

        // If the contact is not already in the ListBox, add the ListItem 
        // object to the Items collection of the ListBox control. 
        if (!ContactsListBox.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="grid_RowCommand" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("xxx")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" CommandArgument=<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %> 
CommandName="arg">Click</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code

```
 protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
int rowindex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
((TextBox)(grid.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("txtgvunit"))).Text
}
```

Ref
http://dotnetinbox.blogspot.in/2014/02/get-gridview-row-data-in-c.html